# C# Connect to WiFi network by Windows Runtime Api. LocalSystem vs NetworkService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-runtime, .net-5

I'm writing simple C# (tried .Net Core 3.1 and .Net 5 with Framework Moniker) console app (will work as a service) for controlling wifi adapters (turn on/off, disconnect, connect).
It works well when running from Visual Studio, works well when running from .exe but "Connect" method does not work when running program as a Network Service.

Sample code for connecting to a network:

```
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var access = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();
            if (access != WiFiAccessStatus.Allowed)
            {
                // No access
            }

            var adapters = await WiFiAdapter.FindAllAdaptersAsync();
            var firstAdapter = adapters.First();

            await firstAdapter.ScanAsync();
            var wifiNetwork = firstAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks.Single(x => x.Ssid == "Wifi_Network_Name");

            var credential = new PasswordCredential {Password = "Wifi_Network_Password"};
            var connectResult = await firstAdapter.ConnectAsync(wifiNetwork, WiFiReconnectionKind.Manual, credential);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

If I run this program as "nt authority\network service" then firstAdapter.ConnectAsync returns UnspecifiedFailure (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi.wificonnectionstatus?view=winrt-19041).
Works well when run as Local System.

I'm using this Windows Runtime API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi?view=winrt-19041

For .Net Core I'm using Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contacts 10.0.19041.1
For .Net 5.0 I'm using Target Framework Moniker: net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0

I guess there is something going on with Network Service privileges or access permissions but can't google anything useful.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated :)